# Ordenar Array por data time em php

Tags: php, array, classificação

Olá,
Já busquei bastante sobre o assunto mas ainda não obtive nada que funcionasse corretamente.
Tenho um banco de dados com vários pedidos e estes tem um prazo de entrega e também data fixa, mas os dados referentes aos prazos não podem ser salvos no banco de dados por estarem sempre mudando de acordo com a data e hora, e aí vem o problema como posso ordenar esta tabela, em ordem de data time crescente de maneira que os indices ou seja, a linha de cada item não pode ser mudado,

Pensei algo tipo usort, mas não funcionou...

```
while ($pRow = mysqli_fetch_object($pQuery)) {
        $ped_id[$w] = $pRow->ped_id;
        $ped_cliente[$w] = $pRow->ped_cliente;
        $ped_entrega[$w] = $data_hs_entrega_print;
        $ped_msg[$w] = $msg;
        $ped_status[$w] = $status;
        $cor[$w] = $cor_chamado;
        $classe[$w] = $class;
        $botoes[$w] = $botao;
        $w++;
}
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
for($g=0;$g<$w;$g++){
    $array['ped_id'][$g] = $ped_id[$g];
    $array['ped_cliente'][$g] = $ped_cliente[$g];
    $array['ped_entrega'][$g] = $ped_entrega[$g];
    $array['ped_msg'][$g] = $ped_msg[$g];
    $array['ped_status'][$g] = $ped_status[$g];
    $array['cor'][$g] = $cor[$g];
    $array['classe'][$g] = $classe[$g];
    $array['botoes'][$g] = $botoes[$g];

    usort($array['ped_entrega'], "sortFunction");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas mudar o item data para o primeiro item do Array e aplicar o arsort(http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php), depois pegar a chave já ordenada e colocar em um for para mudar a posição dos itens do array;

```
    for($g=0;$g<$w;$g++){
        //APagando a Hora
        $teste_data = trim($ped_entrega[$g]);
        if(strstr($teste_data," - ")){
            $vet1 = explode(" - ",$teste_data);
            $data_arr = $vet1[0];
        }
        //Colocando o Formato data Y-m-d
        $teste_data2 = trim($data_arr);
        if(strstr($teste_data2,"/")){
            $vet2 = explode("/",$teste_data2);
            $data_arr2 = $vet2[2] . "-" . $vet2[1] . "-" . $vet2[0];
        }

        $array[$g]['data'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_arr2));
        $array[$g]['id'] = $ped_id[$g];
        $array[$g][2] = $ped_cliente[$g];
        $array[$g][3] = $ped_entrega[$g];
        $array[$g][4] = $data_hs_entrega[$g];
        $array[$g][5] = $ped_msg[$g];
        $array[$g][6] = $ped_status[$g];
        $array[$g][7] = $cor[$g];
        $array[$g][8] = $classe[$g];
        $array[$g][8] = $botoes[$g];
        $array['minutos'][9] = $minutos_array[$g]; //Ordenação do dia por Minutos . . .
    }

arsort($array); 
$e=0;

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $posicao[$e] = $key;
    $e++;
}

for($h=0;$h<$w;$h++){
    $c = $posicao[$h];
    echo $array[$c][3] . "<br/>";
}
```